# How to customise react-google-charts?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-google-charts

I want to customise legends and title of x-Axis and y-Axis in my bar graph. It is a react google chart. Here is my current graph having slanted legends, I want it to be as a graph in second image.

Here is the code for bar graph chart that I want to use.

[slanted legend bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwzSS.png)

[required bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu3vY.png)

'''

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Chart from 'react-google-charts';
import Loader from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/elements/Loader';
import Dimmer from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/modules/Dimmer';

import ErrorMessage from '../vizTab/ErrorMessage';

class BarGraph extends Component {
  state = {}

  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
    const { loading, data } = this.props;

    if (prevProps.loading !== loading && !loading) {
      this.processResponse(data);
    }
  }


  processResponse = (data) => {
    try {
      const keys = Object.keys(data[0] || {});
      const renderArray = [keys].concat(data.map((d) => (
        keys.map((key) => d[key])
      )));

      this.setState({ data: renderArray });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ data: undefined });
    }
  }

  clicked = (row) => {
    const { clicked, data } = this.props;

    if (clicked) clicked(data[row]);
  }

  render = () => {
    const {
      xAxis, yAxis, orientation, slantedTextAngle, loading, colors, noDataMessage, fullWidth,
      groupWidth,
    } = this.props;
    const { data } = this.state;

    let chartType = '';

    if (orientation === 'horizontal') {
      chartType = 'BarChart';
    } else {
      chartType = 'ColumnChart';
    }

    return (
      <div
        className="container-text large ui card centered"
        style={{
          height: '100%', width: '100%', boxShadow: 'none', WebkitBoxShadow: 'none',
        }}
      >
        {loading ? (
          <Dimmer active inverted>
            <Loader>Loading</Loader>
          </Dimmer>
        ) : (
          !data || (data && data.length <= 1) ? (
            <ErrorMessage noDataMessage={noDataMessage} />
          ) : (
            <Chart
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              chartType={chartType}
              loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
              data={data}
              options={{
                hAxis: {
                  title: xAxis,
                  legend: { alignment: 'center' },
                  slantedText: true,
                  slantedTextAngle: parseInt(slantedTextAngle, 10),
                  minValue: 0,
                },
                vAxis: {
                  title: yAxis, minValue: 0,
                },

                colors: colors.split(',') || [],
                bar: { groupWidth: groupWidth || data.length > 4 ? '60%' : '30%' },
                animation: {
                  duration: 300,
                  easing: 'linear',
                  startup: true,
                },
                chartArea: fullWidth === 't' ? {
                  left: '50%', width: '80%',
                } : undefined,
              }}
              chartEvents={[
                {
                  eventName: 'ready',
                  callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
                    const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();

                    google.visualization.events.addListener(
                      chart,
                      'click',
                      (e) => {
                        const { targetID } = e;

                        if (targetID && targetID.match('legend')) {
                          return;
                        }

                        const [, row] = targetID.match(/[0-9]+/g) || [];
                        if (row >= 0) this.clicked(row);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                },
              ]}
            />
          )
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

BarGraph.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
  data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.any),
  clicked: PropTypes.func,
  xAxis: PropTypes.string,
  yAxis: PropTypes.string,
  orientation: PropTypes.string,
  slantedTextAngle: PropTypes.string,
  colors: PropTypes.string,
  noDataMessage: PropTypes.string,
  fullWidth: PropTypes.string,
  groupWidth: PropTypes.string,
};

BarGraph.defaultProps = {
  loading: false,
  data: [],
  clicked: null,
  xAxis: '',
  yAxis: '',
  orientation: 'vertical',
  slantedTextAngle: '30',
  colors: 'green,blue,purple,whisper,red,dodger blue,dark green,maroon,yellow,grey,orange,pink,magenta,teal,brown',
  noDataMessage: '',
  fullWidth: null,
  groupWidth: null,
};

export default BarGraph;
```

'''

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: I've updated the code as well